# Why doesn't Fedora support i686 architecture?

Tags: fedora, system-installation, x86, architecture

My desktop has a i686 CPU running macOS and I'm looking to install Fedora 26 i686. It turns out that they only support x86_64 and i386 (plus the various ARM architectures). I've tried to install Fedora using these two but they have all failed. They both make the shell return

```
dracut-pre-udev[358]: rpcbind: /run/rpcbind/rpcbind.lock: No such file or directory
dracut-pre-udev[358]: rpc.idmapd: conf_reinit: open ("(null)", 0_RDONLY) failed
dracut-pre-udev[358]: rpc.idmapd: conf_reinit: open ("(null)", 0_RDONLY) failed
```

However, when I install Ubuntu 12.04 i686, it works perfectly fine!

I've looked through their [archive](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/) and it turns out the last time they officially released an image with i686 architecture was with Fedora 17 in 2010.

Why doesn't Fedora release Workstation in i686?

Comment: You should be able to run the i386 version but some CPU features may be missing. Not a direct answer, but check the selected answer on ServerFault for [x86, i386, i686, amd64, i5, i7, archtecture, processor confusion](https://serverfault.com/questions/610308/x86-i386-i686-amd64-i5-i7-archtecture-processor-confusion)

Comment: I wrote another [**question**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383916/fedora-26-i386-installation-fails-rpcbind-lock-no-such-file-or-directory) regarding the Fedora installation with i386.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 32-bit images we ship are called `i386` for historical reasons, but are in fact optimized for newer processors and those images include an i686 kernel.

I'm not sure why your system is having problems, but as of 2017, it's not because Fedora doesn't support i686. Note, though, that we are on a path to deprecate it, because the last mainstream Intel-architecture hardware which was not 64-bit-capable was produced about a decade ago. We're finding it hard to find people who are interested in triaging the stream of incoming 32-bit-specific kernel bugs, let alone working on fixing those, and unless that changes it's unlikely i686 support will continue for long. (We will continue to build i686 packages for compatibility, running under a x86_64 kernel.)

That's not the case now, though. Your problem is something else.